# No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5.1

There're lot's of people are having the same issue. However, my question is different here and this is not any duplicate question on StackOverFlow.

My Laravel 5.1 application is running fine on my localhost. However, when I setup it on the production server the first error I'm getting is No supported encrypter found. However, if I run `php artisan key:generate` then all is fine. But that's what I don't want to do as other people may not have skill with command line interface. So, I replaced `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',` to `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` in `config/app.php` which resolved this. However, I don't know what's the negative way by doing this. Is there any recommendation for me to achieve what I want by doing in a standard way?

Comment: You only ever need to run `php artisan key:generate` once, and that's only if you're setting up a new environment. I don't know if I follow your concerns about other people not knowing how the use CLI. Can you make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: I just want to give the app folder to whom I want and they can only upload it to their server and everything should need good to go. That's what I want.

Comment: Hmm... I see. Are you using `git` or some other SCM for managing this project?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `git`.

Comment: Ok. I'll write a quick answer for you then.

Comment: I believe you're telling it to use PHP's mcrypt extension instead of OpenSSL. [Many people think this is a bad idea](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong). I've not used this framework before though, so could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time `php artisan key:generate` needs to be manually called is when moving this project to a new environment, such as a development or production server. The reason you have to do this is this is shown the contents of the default `.gitignore` file:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
.env
```

A copy of this project that is pushed to a new environment will not include `.env`, which has the key `APP_KEY=YourRandomKey` along with `DB_PASSWORD`, `MAIL_PASSWORD`, etc etc. Basically all the stuff you would keep private and allow new environment managers to configure by editing the `.env.example` file that *is* pushed.

If you wanted to push these configuration variables with every copy of your project, you can, but I would **highly recommend against this.**

If you removed `.env` from the `.gitignore` file, the `.env` file would be pushed to your repository and included in any `git clone`ed projects.

Essentially, every copy of your project would have the same `APP_KEY` variable, but it would also expose your `DB_PASSWORD`, along with all other sensitive data found in `.env`. Basically, there is a way to accomplish the level of security you get with Laravel, but in order to accomplish that, you're throwing that security out the window...

Hopefully that gives some insight.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, tried everything the original poster did but it hasn't solved the issue. I handle all of the config files and .env variables individually on each server and have used the `php artisan key:generate` replacing both the .env and config/app.php but still doesn't fix it for me. Would you happen to have any other ideas? I'm running Ubuntu on Amazon EC2 instance and I've been stuck on this for quite a while